# Error! constexpr variable must be initialized by a constant expression constexpr

Tags: c++, debugging, compilation

```
// The constant base "a" that is being used to compute f_{ut}.
constexpr float A_CONST = 6.76;

// The max number of ratings by any given user on a given date. This
// was found by create_f_u_t.py.
constexpr int MAX_NUM_RAT_USER_DATE = 2651;

// The maximum possible value for f_{ut} is the floor of the log base
// "a" of the maximum number of ratings by any user on a given date.
auto BB = std::floor(std::log(MAX_NUM_RAT_USER_DATE)/std::log(A_CONST));


constexpr int MAX_F_U_T = BB;
```

It gives me error! When I compile, it

> says: error: constexpr variable 'MAX_F_U_T' must be initialized by a
>   constant expression
>       constexpr int MAX_F_U_T = BB;

Comment: `log` and `floor` are not constexpr. [There's a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0533r0.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can get `constexpr` versions of `std::floor` and `std::log` in GCC, but I don't think it is ISO C++.  Also don't forget to make `BB` a `constexpr` as well.

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  // The constant base "a" that is being used to compute f_{ut}.
  constexpr float A_CONST = 6.76;

  // The max number of ratings by any given user on a given date. This
  // was found by create_f_u_t.py.
  constexpr int MAX_NUM_RAT_USER_DATE = 2651;

  // The maximum possible value for f_{ut} is the floor of the log base
  // "a" of the maximum number of ratings by any user on a given date.
  constexpr auto BB = std::floor(std::log(MAX_NUM_RAT_USER_DATE)/std::log(A_CONST));

  constexpr int MAX_F_U_T = BB;
}
```

[Demo on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PBL3YvHjKy7mpqjs)

Answer (score -5):

> A constexpr variable must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - its type must be a LiteralType.
> - it must be immediately initialized
> - **the full-expression of its initialization, including all implicit conversions, constructors calls, etc, must be a constant expression**

check [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) for more details