# How does gcc compile C functions in a constexpr context?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, constexpr

Given that [the C++ standard library doesn't (currently) provide constexpr versions of the cmath functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189190/why-doesnt-the-c-standard-library-provide-constexpr-versions-of-the-cmath-fun), consider the program below.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    constexpr auto a = std::pow(2, 10);
    constexpr auto b = std::strlen("ABC");
}
```

As expected, MSVC++ and clang++ fail to compile this, because `constexpr` variables are initialized from functions that are not declared `constexpr`.

g++, however, compiles this.  The version of g++ doesn't seem to matter.

[(See them all in compiler explorer)](https://godbolt.org/z/8robqPznW)

How does g++ achieve this?  Is this correct (allowed) compiler behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the C++ standard library provide constexpr versions of the cmath functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189190/why-doesnt-the-c-standard-library-provide-constexpr-versions-of-the-cmath-fun)

Comment: @康桓瑋 thank you, but no.  I know that C++ currently does not provide `constexpr` versions of <cmath> functions.  Your link implies that g++ should fail to compile this code.

Comment: Is it possible that the standard allows for `constexpr` functions to actually _be_ evaluated in runtime (one time)? I think it allows for that. If so, `constexpr auto a = std::pow(2, 10);` doesn't have to actually be a compile time constant. Speculating a bit ... eggnog...

Comment: @TedLyngmo The initializer of a `constexpr` variable must be a constant expression, otherwise the program is ill-formed. Since `std::pow` is not `constexpr` according to the standard, `std::pow(2, 10);` is not a constant expression and so GCC should produce a diagnostic. But sure, whether it is _actually_ evaluated at compile-time is not specified (in any case).

Comment: @TedLyngmo See "core constant expression" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression. If you try to evaluate a constexpr at compile that isn't core constant you will get a warning something like : this function doesn't evaluate to a constant expression.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Does the standard mandate diagnostict? Does it allow it not to be evaluated at compile time?

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact wording of the standard (and could well be I am missing something in this topic), but I know that clang and MSVC will not compile this : https://godbolt.org/z/bjMfE77jY and will give an error.

Comment: It seems that this error is produced by the used version of the std::floor and std::log methods (GCC compilation), as conceptualized here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44233038/error-constexpr-variable-must-be-initialized-by-a-constant-expression-constexpr

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resolution of [LWG 2013](https://wg21.link/lwg2013) was that implementations are not allowed to declare non-`constexpr` functions as `constexpr`, so gcc is non-conformant by allowing these to be evaluated at compile time.

That said, GCC does not actually mark the needed functions as `constexpr`. What it instead does is replace those calls very early on with `__builtin_pow` and `__builtin_strlen`, which it can compute at compile time (the `std::` versions call the libc versions, which can't). This is a compiler extension.

If you compile with `-fno-builtin`, it also fails to compile both `std::pow` and `std::strlen`, but you can make both clang and GCC compile this by explicitly writing out `__builtin_pow(2, 10)` and `__builtin_strlen("ABC")`.

Answer (score 6):

As noted, the C++ standard library doesn't currently support `constexpr` evaluation of cmath functions. However, that doesn't prevent individual implementations from having non-standard code. GCC has a nonconforming extension that [allows `constexpr` evaluation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++/api/a01013.html).